# Какой знак препинания поставить после слова "автор"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить: "Автор: Василий Пупкин" или "Автор — Василий Пупкин"?

Имя автора — в конце статьи, это принципиально. И нужно ли ставить точку после фамилии автора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно обойтись без слова "автор", просто подписать внизу Василий Пупкин. С выравниванием, как правило, по правому краю. Если наличие данного слова принципиально, то можно и без каких-либо знаков. Пример с Грамоты.ру:
   *Здравствуйте! Ответьте, пожалуйста, на следующий вопрос: Как правильно писать свои инициалы под переведенной статьей, например?*
   *Т.е.:

   Автор: Таня Иванова

   Перевод: Наташа Сидорова

   Или:

   Автор: Таня Иванова

   Перевод Наташи Сидоровой

   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

   Корректно: автор Таня Иванова, перевод Наташи Сидоровой.*
2. Точка в подписи не ставится.